# Differences between isolated and non isolated usb to RS485/RS232 converters

Tags: microcontroller, usb, serial, rs232, rs485

What are the differences between isolated and non isolated usb to RS485/RS232 converters

Comment: One has the data and power connected straight through, the other does not.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams in what way will it help? As in is the main reason only to separate the pc connected to USB and the circuit board(operating at 230V) which is connected to rs485 cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always reccomended to use galvanicaly isolated communication adapters due to the diiferent power supplies at each side. At one side you have a PC with its own PSU and at the other side a MCU, PLC, industrial device,...

Devices with galvanic separation are used in industry (most all of them) and are more expensive. With RS232 there was not possible to power the converter, so an additional power source was neeeded. These days are over, since USB can provide power to the converter. Simple DC/DC converter and magneticaly coupled USB<->RS485 transceiver makes a good and cheap isolated converter. Look for ADM2587E isolator/PSU and Prolific or FTDI usb to rs232 converter.